# python does not quit when the input file is too big

Tags: python, k-mer

I have [a script](https://github.com/tbenavi1/smudgeplot/blob/master/hetkmers.py) that extracts the set of unique kmer pairs from a kmer dump file (& then using them downstream to guess ploidy).

The script seems to work correctly (it's reporting a meaningful set of kmer pairs), but since we have added a parallelization it does not quit when the job is done for really big data sets. The problem is that I never managed to reproduce the behavior with a small reproducible example and it takes around 400G of memory and a day of computation to get to the problem. My imagination is quite limited, I have no idea how should I debug such a problem.

I don't really get it; the script actually prints the last line

> *_families_2.tsv and *_coverages_2.tsv files saved.

, but then it runs further (& forever). I thought it could be related to longer time to free the memory as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412715/python-program-doesnt-quit-when-finished), but it does not seem like the case because it does not quit even after a really long time (I tried to just leave it for a day or so and when i kill it the memory is freed in like 20s).

Does anybody an idea where the problem could be? Or how to figure out?

The reported problem on [GitHub](https://github.com/tbenavi1/smudgeplot/issues/18).

Comment: Can you trace the memory usage of the progress to see if it's related to freeing memory? we had a similar issue some time ago, tried a lot of things like disabling garbage collection etc. but never resolved it. Also have you tried running on another system? our issue was linked to a particular system with an old OS/software

Comment: Also this might fit better on Stack Overflow (although they might complain about it being no small and reproducible)

Comment: After the last line is printed the program seems to occupy exactly the same amount of memory over time.

Comment: I was thinking about posting it to Stack Overflow, but since it's kmer related problem and since I prefer to interact with this community I have decided to post it here.

Comment: As the author [suggested](https://github.com/tbenavi1/smudgeplot/issues/18#issuecomment-426609963), this is probably caused by a deadlock in multi-threading.

Comment: you probably need to do "from multiprocessing import Pool" and not "Queue" or "spawn"

Answer (score 2):

You've hit the RAM bottleneck. Its very common in de novo assemblies and resolved using template assemblies. I don't know this program but suspect it is performing a pairwise analysis for every piece of data in a genomics data set.

The solution is to either:

> 1. find a bigger machine, e.g. a big multi-core machine and make sure the program distributes across every core.
> 2. parallelise the calculation (an excellent way to overcome RAM problems), or,
> 3. find an approximation to the calculation that is less computationally demanding, templates are a good way to circumvent this.